# How to receive URLs with Xamarin Intent Filters

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to write a simple activity with Xamarin for Android that URL's can be shared to (for example, Chrome could share a URL to my activity).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
[Activity (Label = "LinkToDesktop", MainLauncher = true)]
[IntentFilter (new[] {
    Intent.ActionSend,
    Intent.CategoryBrowsable,
    Intent.CategoryDefault,
    })]

public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData") ?? "Data not available";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my app doesn't show up in Chrome's list when I try to Share. And I missing something?

Edit, updated code to what I've posted below. Still doesn't show up as a target when I go to Share from Chrome.

```
[Activity (Label = "LinkToDesktop", MainLauncher = true)]
    [IntentFilter (new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, 
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault })
]
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData") ?? "Data not available";
        }

    protected override void OnNewIntent (Intent intent)
        {
        base.OnNewIntent (intent);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out. The main part I was missing was the DataMimeType.

```
[Activity (Label = "LinkToDesktop", MainLauncher = true)]
[IntentFilter (new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] {
    Intent.CategoryDefault,
    Intent.CategoryBrowsable
}, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (Intent.GetStringExtra (Intent.ExtraText)))
            {
            string subject = Intent.GetStringExtra (Intent.ExtraSubject) ?? "subject not available";
            Toast.MakeText (this, subject, ToastLength.Long).Show ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that the url is in `MyData`? That is not where `ActionSend` is putting the data into the extras.

According to the Android docs `ActionSend` supplies the data in `android.intent.extra.TEXT` through the `Intent.ExtraText`. So:

```
var text = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);
```

Also the two categories you have provided are defined wrongly in your `IntentFilter`. It should look like:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, 
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault })]
```

Comment: I wasn't worried about MyData yet because that code wasn't even being reached.

Comment: Well with the corrected `IntentFilter` is it reached? I know that with NFC you need to get the data in the `OnNewIntent` method instead, so try to override that and see if that is the case here as well.

Comment: No, still doesn't work. I've updated my question with the code I tried.