# open any .jpg image using my application + xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, file-type-associations

I am looking for a code implementation which help me to open any .jpg image of my device can be open by my application. 
I want my application in list of "open with".

Answer (score 0):

> I want my application in list of "open with".

You can add an Intent Filter (via an IntentFilterAttribute) that registers an Activity for that mime type. Then you can read the `Intent` properties to determine what is being shared with your application.

```
[Activity(Label = "JPEG Viewer/Editor", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "image/jpeg")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

     ~~~

}
```

[image]

Comment: I did the same. My application appears into openwith but image is not open into my app.

Comment: @Query `... image is not open into my app....` That is a different question then the one you asked.  You have to read the Intent properties sent to the Activity and act upon them, what is your code doing in that regard?

Comment: @sushilhangover - can you pls help me with some good examples or any demo written i  xamarin android.

Comment: @Query There are lots of example on the web, just Google/Bing it, also there are a number of SOs regarding how to receive shared URLs:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255321/4984832 Once you have the URL of the shared item, you, of course, need to do something with it, Xamarin has hundreds of code demos with quite a few dealing with IntentFilter: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples